# Find certain colons in string using Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to search for colons in a given string  so as to split the string at the colon for preprocessing based on the following conditions

1. Preceeded or followed by a word e.g `A Book: Chapter 1` or `A Book :Chapter 1`
2. Do not match if it is part of emoticons i.e `:( or ): or :/ or :-)` etc
3. Do not match if it is part of a given time i.e `16:00` etc

I've come up with a regex as such

`(\:)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(\:)`

which satisfies conditions 2 & 3 but still fails on condition 3 as it matches the colon present in the string representation of time. How do I fix this?

edit: it has to be in a single regex statement if possible

Comment: Do you need a single regex, or can you compose multiple regexes in conventional control structures? (E.g. `if( myRegexForConditions1and2.match( input ) && !timeRegex.match( input ) ) { …`)

Comment: I need it in a single regex as I'm using python's `re` package to search for the pattern

Comment: `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. You can use `[a-zA-Z]` to only match letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(:\b|\b:)(?!(?:(?<=\b\d:)|(?<=\b\d{2}:))\d{1,2}\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/esvhN4/2). *Details*:

- `(:\b|\b:)` - Group 1: a `:` that is either preceded or followed with a word char
- `(?!(?:(?<=\b\d:)|(?<=\b\d{2}:))\d{1,2}\b)` - there should be no one or two digits right after `:` (followed with a word boundary) if the `:` is preceded with a single or two digits (preceded with a word boundary).

Note `:\b` is equal to `:(?=\w)` and `\b:` is equal to `(?<=\w):`.

If you need to get the same capturing groups as in your original pattern, replace `(:\b|\b:)` with `(?:(:)\b|\b(:))`.

**More flexible solution**

Note that excluding matches can be done with a simpler pattern that matches and *captures* what you need and just matches what you do not need. This is called ["best regex trick ever"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick). So, you may use a regex like

```
8:|:[PD]|\d+(?::\d+)+|(:\b|\b:)
```

[that will match](https://regex101.com/r/esvhN4/4) `8:`, `:P`, `:D`, one or more digits and then one or more sequences of `:` and one or more digits, or will match and capture into Group 1 a `:` char that is either preceded or followed with a word char. All you need to do is to check if Group 1 matched, and implement required extraction/replacement logic in the code.

Comment: If  I want to exclude other emoticons like `8:` `:D` `:P` , should the changes be done to the regex in Group 1?

Comment: @Naja You would either go on with lookarounds, like [this regex here](https://regex101.com/r/esvhN4/3), `(?<!8)(:\b|\b:)(?!(?:(?<=\b\d:)|(?<=\b\d{2}:))\d{1,2}\b|[PD])`, or you can use a capturing group around the pattern you want to extract and just match what you need to skip, something like `8:|:[PD]|\d+(?::\d+)+|(:\b|\b:)`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/esvhN4/4).

Answer (score 2):

Word characters `\w` include numbers `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
So just use `[a-ZA-Z]` instead

`(\:)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(\:)`

[Test Here](https://regex101.com/r/Ma7TqO/1)